# Zero-dimensional space with multiple objects

Tags: philosophy, dimension-theory-analysis

I am unsure if this belongs to math or philosophy.

Let's say there's 0-dimensional space, however multiple objects exist within in, occupying the same "spot". If multiple objects exist, is the space still zero-dimensional?

The problem here is that multiple objects existing at the same spot introduces dimensionality. If objects exist, they are somehow distinct, and can be ordered around.

At the same time, as far as I know, there is no axiom saying that only one point can exist at given coordinates. And in 3d space, each point of space can have phenomenon associated with it, which may require a higher-dimensional construct to represent it. For example, electromagnetic spectrum at a point could be expressed as 1-dimensional line.

This implies that a single point can have a set of properties associated with it, which can be expressed in dimensional way, but that does not affect dimensionality of the space itself, as they do not form a spatial dimension.

Which line of reasoning is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only zero dimensional space, by definition, is the space containing only one element, the zero element. This means that a zero dimensional space cannot have multiple objects existing within it. All reasoning after we assume the existence of such a space is meaningless.

Comment: Could you provide a link to such definition in a currently accepted math book or theory that supports this stance? Because common definitions are:

"A 0-Dimensional Space is a space in which every position can be described in a point. In other words, there is only one possible position in zero dimensional space, so no information is required to describe the location."

Comment: @SigTerm The word "dimension" (like the word "infinity") refers to different things depending on the context. There's no universal definition, while all definitions capture some common, ineffable concept. This answer is using a definition from linear algebra. There's also the [inductive dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension) from topology, which allows for zero-dimensional spaces to contain arbitrarily large sets of points. Your definition in your comment is not one I've seen, and is not precise.

Comment: @SigTerm I have no idea where you got your definition from, but it certainly does not look like it's from a math textbook. The mathematical definition of "dimension" is a fundamental concept of linear algebra and is included in any linear algebra textbook out there. The definition is that for a vector space, the dimension of the vector space is the cardinality of its basis (note that there is a theorem saying that all bases of a vector space must have the same cardinality, so that definition is valid).

Comment: @SigTerm Note that there exist other definitions of the word "dimension" in some other fields of mathematics, but if you are just talking about "dimension" to a mathematitian, it is assumed that you are talking about the linear algebraic dimension of a vector space.

Comment: @5xum The definition I quoted is layman definition which my search engine pulled out of somewhere. I came across the one you mentioned a bit later, but the issue is that this definition does not explicitly indicate that multiple points cannot have the same position. I also do not recall anything similar from basic geometric axioms.  

I can agree that there cannot be multiple distinct coordinates referring to the same position in most of normal spaces, though.

Hmm. Actually thinking about it. Are you meaning to say, that for a mathematician, "point" means "coordinates"?

Comment: @SigTerm Well if we are talking about *mathematics*, then a layman definition won't do. We cannot ask mathematical question about objects which are vaguely defined.

Comment: 5xum: See the part of the comment I edited. 

Are you saying that mathematical definition is "point is coordinates"? Because if a point is coordinates I can see how only one can exist at any location,. As there cannot be multiple different numbers that are equal.

Comment: @SigTerm The phrase "'Point' means 'coordinates'" is again a very vague sentence that cannot really be answered mathematically. In a vector space, the elements of the vector space are called vectors. If a vector space has zero dimensions, then it has one element which is the zero vector.

Comment: @SigTerm Note that if you select a particular *basis* of a vector field, then you can, for every vector, uniquely define the *coordinates* of that vector (and these coordinates will be tuples of scalars). The coordinates will be in a one-to-one correspondence with the vectors, meaning that no two vectors can have the same coordinate tuples, nor can two coordinate tuples represent the same vector.

Comment: @SigTerm Also, in the case of the zero dimensional vector field, the only basis it has is the empty set, and in that basis, the only element (the zero vector) corresponds to the empty tuple - so the one to one correspondence still hods, i.e. you have one vector (the zero vector) that matches up to one coordinate tuple (the empty tuple).

Comment: @5xum: RE: "'Point' means 'coordinates'" is again a very vague". The meaning of the phrase is that "mathematical point represents location in space and not a thing that can exist at a location". Because location is coordinates in said space, and because no two different numbers can be equal and location is a collection of such numbers, hence no two locations can be the same, and as such there can be no two points at the same location, because points are locations. That uses non-mathematical terminology, but I think it can be understood.  If that's the reasoning, then I get it.

Comment: @5xum: in this scenario, the question moves outside of mathematics. Towards "can a zero dimensional space contain multiple things and still be zero-dimensional". But this probably goes outside of scope of this stackexchange. Anyway, thanks for the chat. It did clear few things up.

Comment: @SigTerm What a mathematical point represents is not a question for mathematics. A mathematical point simply is what it is, a mathematical point. It is neither a location in  space, nor is it a thing that exists at a location. It is an abstract object that is an element of a vector space. That object can be used to represent either a location or a thing at a location, depending on what you want to use it for. Or it can represent something completely different, like a direction.

Comment: @SigTerm So this is where I think your problem stems for. You took two different things, both represented as mathematical points, and then noticed that the two things have different (and conflicting) properties. But that's completely normal. Of course they have them, that's why they are different things. All your reasoning has really shown that the concept of "dimension" is not trivially translatable to real world objects.

Comment: @5xum: Aha. So I mixed math concept with things such concept may represent. 
Alright, got it. I'll pick your answer as accepted, as discussion in comments is going to be helpful to whoever may stumble on this in the future. Thanks for the assistance.